# Merge conflict in a fast forward merge

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, merge-conflict-resolution

I have two branches B and A . B is the base of A . A1 is the first commit of A. Then I have several commits A2, A3, A4 and two merges back to B as shown below :

```
B1 ---------B2----------- B3  (Branch B)
  \        /             /
    A1----A2-----A3-----A4      (Branch A)
```

Thing is that I am getting a merge conflict on merging A4 back to B(B3) . How can this be possible ? This is supposed to be a fast forward merge .

#### Potential hint

A4 is a commit from a feature branch, whose history is :

1. checkout from A2
2. Commit something
3. Commit something else
4. Merge A (to get latest changes aka A3)
5. Merged to A thus creating A4

Could it be the case that command number 4(merge A) caused this issue because it was a merge and not a rebase , and if yes how ?

Comment: yes, I wanted in one graph to have them both . A and B are the branches and I have 6 commits( A1 to A4 and the two merges) .

Comment: Then you've labelled them in the wrong place: in git, a branch is a pointer to the *most recent commit* in a sequence; history is traced *backwards* using the "parents" of each commit.

Comment: Is it better now ? I have exhausted my knowledge and artistic potential !

Comment: *caused this issue* what issue? Merge conflicts happen... Just resolve them? It's really not clear what the problem is here

Comment: so merge conflicts can occur in a fast forward merge ? Are you sure ?

Comment: This is actually not a fast-forward merge, because commit B2 is not on A.

Comment: Are A2 and B2 actually identical? Run `git diff A2 B2` to see. That diff might also reveal the source of the merge conflict when you're trying to merge A4 into B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fast-forward merge requires the tip of one branch to be an ancestor of the other.

If we look at your diagram, before the merge:

```
B1 ---------B2   (Branch B)
  \        /            
    A1----A2-----A3-----A4      (Branch A)
```

Note that there is no path backwards from B2 (the tip of branch B) to A4; nor is there any path backwards from A4 (the tip of branch A) to B2. So neither `git switch A; git merge B`; nor `git switch B; git merge A` can result in a fast-forward merge.

To put it a different way: if we moved branch A to commit B2, we would lose commits A3 and A4; if we moved branch B to commit A4, we would lose commit B2. So we need to create a new commit which has both A4 and B2 as parents, and move a branch pointer to that.

You even show this yourself, by adding a commit B3:

```
B1 ---------B2----------- B3  (Branch B)
  \        /             /
    A1----A2-----A3-----A4      (Branch A)
```

A fast-forward merge does not create any new commits, it just moves branch pointers. For instance, if we instead start with this (where A2 has A1 and B2 as parents):

```
B1 ----- B2  (Branch B)
  \       \             
    A1---- A2-----A3-----A4      (Branch A)
```

Here, B2 is an ancestor of A4, so `git switch B; git merge A` can result in a fast-forward merge, giving this:

```
B1 ----- B2 
  \       \             
    A1---- A2-----A3-----A4      (Branch A, Branch B)
```

As you say, no conflict is possible in a fast-forward merge, because no changes are being applied; there's just a change in how existing commits are labelled. But your merge wasn't a fast-forward, so there is always a possibility of merge conflicts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. So in my scenario the conflict can be justified if A2 has a conflict with A4 as A2 is reflected in B2 ?

Comment: @CapBarracudas What do you mean by "justified"? A conflict happens whenever two sets of changes can't both be applied at the same time. In this case, the common base is commit A2, so roughly speaking you have two patches: `git diff A2 B2` and `git diff A2 A4`. If those two patches both touch the same parts of the same files, you get a conflict. Presumably, B2 doesn't have code identical to A2, but incorporates some other changes not shown.